# VCO with Software Issues

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, analog-digital-converter, mbed

I have a VCO with an AD5791 and LPC1768. I am able to read and write to the DAC register of the AD5791 but unable to modify the output frequency or voltage. When the AD5791 is directly connected to a power supply, I can modify the frequency as expected. Therefore I believe this is a software issue. My code is here:

```
#include "mbed.h"

SPI spi(p5, p6, p7); // mosi, miso, sclk
DigitalOut cs(p8);
DigitalOut LDAC(p9);
DigitalOut Reset(p11);
DigitalOut CLR(p10);

int main()
{
   spi.format(8,0);
   spi.frequency(10000); // you can speedup later
   cs = 1;

   Reset = 0;
   wait_us(1);
   LDAC = 0;
   CLR = 1;
   Reset = 1; // the chip is reset now

   cs = 0;
   spi.write(20);
   spi.write(0);
   spi.write(0);
   cs= 1; // this will activate dac

   cs = 0;
   spi.write(0x14);
   spi.write(0xCC);
   spi.write(0xCD);
   cs = 1; // set output register - shall output some value

   do{
   }while(1); // wait forever to test the output value

}
```

Any inputs would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can change the VCO frequency by adjusting the power supply voltage, but not by writing to the DAC that is supposed to control it in operation.  Is the DAC perhaps double (or even multiply) buffered such that it required additional clocks to actually change output?  Is the chip in the right mode?

Comment: @Chris Yes, that is the current state of affairs! I think spi.write() is possibly incorrectly setting the clock as well. I am not sure how to fix that though. On the AD5791 datasheet, I have the timing diagram, but am not sure how to implement it. I have never bit-banged before. On your other point, I do believe the chip is in the correct state as I initialized it (https://wiki.analog.com/resources/quick-start/ad5791). However, much of this is new to me - so I could have not correctly initialized the chip (AD5791). What do you think?

Comment: How are you driving /LDAC?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I was just thinking I might need to manually set LDAC. I previously thought spi.write() would handle that. I am going to rewrite my code and try that.

Comment: My reading of the data sheet is that you will have to explicitly do something with /LDAC, which is not really part of the SPI-like interface.  It looks like you have a few choices for how to use it, but you will have to manipulate it, and can't just leave it at a fixed level.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thank you again for the quick reply! Here is a copy of one of the unsuccessful variations I have tried: https://gist.github.com/tashwoods/84c81f87fa6e0f1b98a2
I think I am either not setting LDAC properly, the initialization of the chip, and/or the clock mode is off. What do you think?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I got it to work! https://gist.github.com/tashwoods/84c81f87fa6e0f1b98a2
Thank you again!!!

Comment: Congratulations and thanks for letting us know.  So that this doesn't stick around looking unresolved, please either post a few sentences description of your fix as an answer which you can eventually accept, or else delete the question if you think the problem was personally unique and no one else would benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here was that the LPC1768 had to have its software control register and control register set before writing to it. Additionally, the chip had to be driven by LDAC with pauses after data was transferred. This can be seen in my code here: https://gist.github.com/tashwoods/84c81f87fa6e0f1b98a2